# Why don't EMR instances have as many reducers as mappers?

Tags: memory, hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce, reducers

By default during an EMR job, instances are configured to have fewer reducers than mappers.  But the reducers aren't given any extra memory so it seems like they should be able to have the same amount.  (For instance, extra-large high-cpu instances have 7 mappers, but only 2 reducers, but both mappers and reducers are configured with 512 MB of memory available).

Does anyone know why this is and is there some way I can specify to use as many reducers as mappers?

EDIT: I had the amount wrong, it's 512 MB

Comment: I think I understand now, but I'm not sure.  The amount of memory listed in http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HadoopMemoryDefault_AMI2.html is across all mappers or all reducers, it's not per-reducer because they all run in the same JVM

Answer (score 3):

Mappers extract data from their input stream (the mapper's STDIN), and what they emit is much more compact.  That outbound stream (the mapper's STDOUT) is also then sorted by the key.  Therefore, the reducers have smaller, sorted data in their incoming.

That is pretty much the reason why the default configuration for any Hadoop MapReduce cluster, not just EMR, is to have more mappers than reducers, proportional to the number of cores available to the jobtracker.

You have the ability to control the number of mappers and reducers through the jobconf parameter.  The configuration variables are mapred.map.tasks and mapred.reduce.tasks.

Comment: But in that case, why is the JVM's allotted memory the same (512 MB), also does that apply to all the reducers or is that per reducer?
More importantly, can I safely give the reducers a lot more memory?

Comment: It's a default configuration.  If you go back through the different versions you'll see that some of these formulas are simply a result of best-practices (specifically the ratio of mappers to reducers.)    See: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/mapred_tutorial.html#Reducer.  A bit down that document there's a discussion of memory management, including the heap size.  These are all configurable, so if your reducer has a different behavior profile you can modify how your Hadoop job behaves (including EMR).

Comment: My question is what's all the other memory being used for?  The c1.xlarge instance is supposed to have 7 GB, but it's only allotting 512 MB to each task.  Is there something else using up the rest of the memory.  If I change that to say 4 GB, will the instance run out of memory?  Will something else suffer as a result?

Comment: It's being conservative, which leaves you with room to tweak.  There is an amount of memory used by the tasktracker, if you're using the local HDFS the datanode on that instance is also using up memory.  The rest is given to the mappers and reducers, which EMR assumes may be up concurrently for a while.  It's trying to avoid swapping.  However, it's very simple for you to tune and test.  Find a test and run it several times with the same instances and cluster size, but with a different heap size declared for the mappers.

Comment: By the way, I think you should also test with a different type of instance.  For most tasks it's better to have more cores (which means more concurrency) than more memory.  What about a cluster of m1.large, or if need be m1.xlarge?

Comment: c1.xlarge has the most cores and the most concurrency.  It's more than m1.xlarge